# Set custom user-agent value in Microsoft Outlook Today

Tags: outlook, user-agent

I am setting a custom HTML page saved in locally as Outlook Today. It actually has links to other web pages (for example: www.gmail.com). The linked page loads in Outlook Today window [this sentence is added later].

There are links in the page which leads to a site where the request needs to have a certain user-agent value.

Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't be able to manipulate the user agent through a link. You'd likely have to configure the user's browser, e.g. using a browser extension that allows you to set the user agent.

Comment: Thanks @Pekka웃 for the info. I shall look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide any way for specifying the user-agent string in the HTTP header. Instead, you may consider developing an add-in with an adjucent Outlook window where you can use a web browser control. See [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) for more information.